# Can well-ordering of the universe due to global choice survive extensive failure of Extensionality?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

That axiom of global choice leads to the well-ordering of the universe given the other axioms of Zermelo set theory is a famous result.

Now, if we weaken the power set axiom to the axiom stating that for any set $X$ there is a set that has a co-extensional copy of every subset of $X$ among its elements. Formally:

$\forall X \exists Y \forall S \subseteq X \exists M \in Y: \forall k (k \in M \leftrightarrow k \in S)$

Let $\sf Z^*F^*GC$-$\sf Ext.$ stand for $\sf ZF$ with schema of replacement replaced by the Collection schema together with the Separation scheme, and Power set axiom weakened to the above principle, and of course choice replaced by global choice (by adding a new primitive total unary function symbol $C$ and axiomatizing $C(X) \in X$ for every nonempty $X$ and $C(X)=X$ for each empty $X$). $\sf Ext$ stands for axiom of Extensionality.

> Is the well-ordering of the universe a theorem of $\sf Z^*F^*GC$-$\sf Ext.$?

Comment: To be clear, you are keeping the axiom of foundation, right?

Comment: @JamesHanson. Yes!